# Edit the footer and delete any of the footer

Tags: prestashop

This is how I sit with a little problem that I can not take it away as has the red arrow and can not be right in the green arrow, how do I do it?, Hope you can help me further

I want the RED AWAY!

and the Greens I would be right, for example write something else or look like;)

You can see it here

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The red arrow is a module called "blockreinsurance". You can override this content by creating a template to the right folder : 
"themes/mytheme/modules/blockreinsurance/blockreinsurance.tpl"

The green arrow is a mix of the footer and other modules, the easiest way to find out is to look at the source code, most of them have a comment before the block saying which module it is.